# Error in my gradient descent function: Unable to perform assignment because the left and right sides have a different number of elements

Tags: matlab

I am getting an error for my gradient descent algorithm. It seems that the error doesn't really have to do with the functionality of the actual gradient descent, but rather with a part of the function which keeps track of the cost for each iteration of gradient descent.

Here is the line of code that sparks the error:

```
theta = gradientDescent(X, y, theta, alpha, iterations);
```

The error then says: **"Unable to perform assignment because the left and right sides have a different number of elements."**

But then underneath it says: "error in gradientDescent line 30..." and then refers to this line in my gradient descent function:

```
J_history(iter) = computeCost(X, y, theta);
```

I am sooooo confused.

Here is the full gradient descent function code:

```
function [theta, J_history] = gradientDescent(X, y, theta, alpha, num_iters)
%GRADIENTDESCENT Performs gradient descent to learn theta
%   theta = GRADIENTDESCENT(X, y, theta, alpha, num_iters) updates theta by 
%   taking num_iters gradient steps with learning rate alpha

% Initialize some useful values
m = length(y); % number of training examples
J_history = zeros(num_iters, 1);

for iter = 1:num_iters

    % ====================== YOUR CODE HERE ======================
    % Instructions: Perform a single gradient step on the parameter vector
    %               theta. 
    %
    % Hint: While debugging, it can be useful to print out the values
    %       of the cost function (computeCost) and gradient here.
    %
    h = X*theta;
    errors = h - y;

    theta = theta - alpha*(1/m)*sum(errors).*transpose(X);






    % ============================================================
    J_history(iter) = computeCost(X, y, theta);
    % Save the cost J in every iteration    


end

end
```

Any insight here would be soooo appreciated.

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: What is `computeCost` doing?  The message suggests that it's returning something other than a single number.

Comment: @bg2b as far as I can tell, computeCost just returns a single value!! "function J = computeCost(X, y, theta)

m = length(y); % number of training examples
J = 0;
h = X*theta;
error = h - y;
error_sqr = error.^2;
J = 1/(2*m) * sum(error_sqr);
end"

Comment: What values are you passing in for the arguments?

Comment: @bg2b >> computeCost(X, y, theta)

ans =

   32.0727

Comment: @bg2b there is an example of me calling the computeCost function in the command terminal

Comment: @bg2b X = data(:, 1); y = data(:, 2); theta = zeros(2, 1);

Comment: Just looking at the code, `theta` is probably supposed to be a single number.  What shape is `data`?  No, maybe not.  Let me think about it for a minute.

Comment: @bg2b okay, thank you for trying to help. I am soooo frustrated here. It's confusing because as you see, when I call computeCost(), it returns one singular number. And then I look at the other side of the equation, J_history(iter) and that is a singular slot that the computeCost()'s number should perfectly fit in...So why is it saying unable to assign!? Ughhhh fml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214083/discussion-between-mark-d-foti-and-bg2b).

Comment: @bg2b solved the problem for me in a private chat room with the answer "Update is maybe wrong, perhaps theta = theta - alpha*(1/m)*X'*errors;" Thank you!!!

Comment: @MarkD.Foti answer your own question then